# What is the variable valertpubkey in net.cpp for?

Tags: bitcoind, public-key, regtest

```
vAlertPubKey = ParseHex("04fc9702847840aaf195de8442ebecedf5b095cdbb9bc716bda9110971b28a49e0ead8564ff0db22209e0374782c093bb899692d524e9d6a6956e7c5ecbcd68284");
```

The `vAlertPubKey` variable can be seen in the initialisations for `main` and `test` network, but not for `regtest`. Can someone explain what it exactly means and how will it affect me if I want to simulate a network of 1000 or more nodes on a private network in `regtest` mode ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the people who holds the private key corresponding to that public key (Satoshi, theymos, Gavin, and [unspecified others](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/2dz9ri/why_in_the_world_does_theymos_have_the_private/cjuu360)) has the ability to send a message out to everyone on the network. This has been used in the past to tell people about security vulnerabilities in the client.

> Can someone explain what it exactly means and how will it affect me if I want to simulate a network of 1000 or more nodes on a private network in `regtest` mode ?

Assuming you're not testing the alert system, it won't affect you.